# Chrome HTML5 Video - Blurs webpage on resize

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, video.js

I'm using the BigVideo.js plugin (http://dfcb.github.io/BigVideo.js/) in a website of mine.  I am also using the following Javascript to scale the site up or down as the user resizes their browser.

```
$(document).ready(function() {
     scaleSite();
});

$( window ).resize(function() {
    scaleSite();
});

// Scale Site to Fit Window
function scaleSite() {
    var windowWidth = $( window ).width();
    var defaultWidth = 1200;
    var scaleWidth = 1;
    var isMobile = false; 
    if( /Android|webOS|iPhone|iPad|iPod|BlackBerry|IEMobile|Opera Mini/i.test(navigator.userAgent) ) {
        // MOBILE ACTIONS   
    } else {
        // STANDARD ACTIONS
        if(windowWidth >= defaultWidth) {
            scaleWidth = windowWidth/defaultWidth;
            var scaleWidthRounded = Math.round( scaleWidth * 10 ) / 10;
        } else {
            scaleWidth = windowWidth/defaultWidth;
            var scaleWidthRounded = Math.round( scaleWidth * 10 ) / 10;
        }
        $("#mainDiv").css("-webkit-transform", "scale("+scaleWidth+")");
        $("#mainDiv").css("-moz-transform", "scale("+scaleWidth+")");
        $("#mainDiv").css("-o-transform", "scale("+scaleWidth+")");
        $("#mainDiv").css("msTransform", "scale("+scaleWidth+")");

        $("#fixedHeader").css("-webkit-transform", "scale("+scaleWidth+")");
        $("#fixedHeader").css("-moz-transform", "scale("+scaleWidth+")");
        $("#fixedHeader").css("-o-transform", "scale("+scaleWidth+")");
        $("#fixedHeader").css("msTransform", "scale("+scaleWidth+")");

        // RESET BODY HEIGHT
        var mainDivHeight = ($("#mainDiv").height()*scaleWidthRounded);
        $("body").css("height", mainDivHeight);
        $("html").css("height", mainDivHeight);
    }
}
```

Strangely enough, when I load a page that has a video playing on it, and I try to resize the browser, the scaling works correctly but everything BUT the video gets a little blurred.

I had trouble with this same issue when using the Jssor Slider plugin, it also caused my pages to blur after resizing the browser window.  I resolved that issue by adding the $HWA : false to the options for the Jssor Slider, which disabled the plugins ability to use Hardware Acceleration.

Is there something in the BigVideo.js or the underlying Video.js file that I can adjust to prevent hardware acceleration there as well?  As it seems to be the same cause.

**UPDATE**

I just noticed the blur issue ONLY happens in Chrome.  Firefox and Internet Explorer both work fine with no problem, but in Chrome, all content on the page OTHER than the BigVideo itself gets slightly blurred.

**UPDATE 2**

Okay, so I just noticed that if I inspect element on the div containing the HTML5 `<video>` tag and I delete it from the DOM, my text "snaps" back into focus.  I went through the div item by item and unchecked CSS styles thinking that would lead me to the one that is causing problems but still no luck.

Why would deleting the element from the DOM in the Chrome DEV tools snap the rest of the page back into focus and remove the blur?

Below is a screen shot showing an example of the text on my page BEFORE I resize the browser window, and the result AFTER I resize.  Again, if I resize, the page gets a bit blurry, and if I delete the element containing the `<video>` using the Chrome DEV tools, the blur goes away.

[image]

**UPDATE 3**

So I removed the BigVideo plugin and replaced it with a generic HTML5 `<video>` tag, the video still plays and the blur issue is still present when resizing the browser.  So it's something with the way chrome is handling the HTML5 video along with my scale site script.

**JSFIDDLE**

https://jsfiddle.net/h5vu7La7/3/

Not sure if this will help or not, but if you resize the window on this jsFiddle you can see the text (in Chrome) is blurred a bit.  If you remove the `<video>` from the HTML and re-run and resize it does not blur.

Also noticed if you run the fiddle, and inspect element on the video and delete it from the DOM, the text snaps back into focus.

Comment: What "div with the HTML5 tag"? And you're showing javascript but not a simplified version of the page.

Comment: @Rob jsFiddle provided.

Comment: @Phil I encountered exactly the same issue with generic WebKit so I suppose is a bug of WebKit renderer engine, did you sort on how to fix this issue?

Answer (score 0):

If you are applying transform scale CSS rule to a HTML element that has child elements (I'm guessing those visible in the pictures are inside one of the divs you are scaling), they will get somewhat blurry due the layer moving to 3D plane.

Open inspector and apply `transform: scale(1.01);` to the blue button below here on SO and you'll realize what I mean.

Instead of scale, you should just resize the width and height of the video element.

Comment: I'm confused.  Why would the scale work perfectly when I remove the video element from the page?  But with the video element all the content on the page gets a little blurred EXCEPT the video?

Comment: That I do not know. :)